# pgAdmin not working on mac OS Big Sur

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, macos-bigsur

I updated my Mac to macOS Big Sur a few days ago and tried to run [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org) to work on some projects of mine. However, it seems there is a problem with pgAdmin 4 and Big Sur. I just cannot run it thererfore I cannot use it to connect to PostgreSQL.

I uninstalled PostgreSQL and installed the latest version (v13.1) but it didn't solve my problem.

Is this a known compatibility issue?

Before updating my Mac to Big Sur, when I launched pgAdmin, it would open a new tab in my browser to let me access my database, and add an icon to the menu bar. Now when I launch pgAdmin nothing happens. It seems to be running if I look in the activity monitor (more than 90% CPU usage) but I don't have access to it.

Comment: “It just won't copy itself into my application folder.” What do you mean? Like you try to drag it into your applications folder and it won’t copy? Or something else? Now you have edited your question to focus on PostgreSQL and not pgAdmin? This is confusing. Can you please clarify what has been updated?

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. To clarify, I installed the latest version of PostgreSQL which comes with pgAdmin. Before updating my Mac to Big Sur, when I launched pgAdmin, it would open a new tab in my browser to let me access my database  and add an icon to the menu bar. Now when I launch pgAdmin nothing happens. It seems to be running if I look in the activity monitor (more than 90% CPU usage) but I don't have access to it :(

Comment: I'm still able to access PostgreSQL through Postbird but pgAdmin won't open :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating to latest version of PGAdmin 4(released on 12th Nov) fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Is it part of PostgreSQL 13 or do I have to update pgAdmin seperately? Thanks,

Comment: Only update pgAdmin to latest

Comment: Thanks, it worked :)

Comment: The solution works with nov 12th version, but it will not with any new updates after it such as dec 10, and Jan 28.